# Pointcut for specific methods of one class

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

As far as I know, there are two ways to achieve this:

1. Using annotation based pointcuts:
   Just add annotation to these methods, and use @annotation in pointcut expression.

   ```java
   @Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)")
   public void myPointcut() {}
   ```
2. use many many execution expressions

   ```java
   @Pointcut("execution(* me.mypackage.MyClass.method0(*))||" +
             "execution(* me.mypackage.MyClass.method1(*))||"+
             "execution(* me.mypackage.MyClass.method2(*))||"+
             "execution(* me.mypackage.MyClass.method3(*))||"+
             "execution(* me.mypackage.MyClass.method4(*))")
   public void myPointcut() {}
   ```

First method should be much more convenient. However I don't want to add additional custom annotations to these methods. In my situation, I just want to make my pointcuts "invisible" for these methods.
So, I have to use the second method. But it seems too complex for me, is there any way to shorten this expression?

Answer (score 1):

Just combine within and execution, it should work fine.

```
@Pointcut("within(me.packages.TargetClass)")
public void classPointcut() {}
@Pointcut("execution(* method1(*)) && execution(* method2)")
public void methodPointcut() {}
```

And to bind the advice, for example, around the advice:

```
@Around("classPointcut() && methodPointcut()")
public Object foo(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp)
```

Comment: For a complete answer you should also have mentioned _how_ to actually combine the pointcuts and not just _that_ you can combine them. I mean something like `@Before("classPointcut() && methodPointcut()")`. As you are clearly an AOP beginner and thus your answer also mainly helps other beginners, this information is important to make the answer useful to them.